# Link from Wall to Application Tab that do not open a new window

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-wall

I know this is meant for programming questions, but I just can't seem to find any information on this anywhere, so here goes nothing:

I have a Facebook page to which I added a custom Application tab. Now I'd like to be able to post a link to that Application tab that doesn't open in a new window/browser tab.

Using an url shortener I was able to post the link, but when clicking the link the url is opened in a new window, which in my opinion is not necessary. I'd like to know if there is a way to not open a new window.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot change the default behavior of the facebook wall. If is there where you want to post the link, you have nohing to do with it. Sorry.